# Await all Mongo queries with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

Code below has a flaw as I am getting array of `undefined`:

```js
let filters = [];

async function getFilters(tiers) {

    return await Promise.all(

        tiers.map(async t => {
            let id = new ObjectId(t.filter);

            filters.push(
                await conn.collection('TierScheduleFilter').find({
                    _id: id
                }).toArray(function(err, filter) {
                    if (err || !filter) {
                        reject('no filter || error');
                    }

                    return filter;
                });
            );
        });
    );
}
await getFilters(tiers);
console.log(filters); // 4 filters => [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

The code shall retrieve all filters but its all undefined values.

Comment: Is this all inside another async function? You can't declare `await`s outside async functions.

Comment: Something like `getFilters(tiers).then(x => console.log(filters))` (note: pseudocode) will possibly work for you. Because your code is no longer synchronous, your console.log is being run before the rest of your code has a chance to complete.

Comment: ... if you don't force the console.log to run _after_ the getFilters call is complete, it will always print undefined as that stuff hasn't finished evaluating at that point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be a proper approach:

```js
let filters = [];
    async function getFilters(tiers) {
        return await Promise.all(
                tiers.map(async t => {
                        let id = new ObjectId(t.filter);
                        try {
                            return await conn.collection('TierScheduleFilter').findOne({ _id: id })
                        } catch (e) {
                            return e;
                        }
                }))
    }
```